# Dirac delta function and its property

Tags: fourier-analysis, dirac-delta

I am trying to find a formal proof for the following property of Dirac delta function:

for any function $f$ : $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(x)f(x)dx=f(0),$$ where $\delta$ is Dirac delta generalized function.

Sorry if the above $f$ must have some properties but I think it shouldn't. That is what I want the whole text and the proof.

Is there anyone who knows?

Comment: This is more or less the definition of $\delta$ ($f$ should be continuous on a neighborhood of $0$ for it to make sense).

Comment: You need the theory of distributions to understand why that property holds. You cannot use real calculus, because $\delta(x)$ is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as you were told, there is no *proof* of the formula you're asking, this is a definition. However, here is the way why the expression on the left is used in so many contexts.

Consider a sequence of function
$$
\delta_\epsilon(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2\epsilon},&-\epsilon<x<\epsilon,\\
0,&\mbox{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

It is reasonable to expect that 
$$
\delta(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\delta_\epsilon(x).
$$

Now consider the integral and assume that we are free to change the order of operations:
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}\delta(x)f(x)dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{\mathbb R}\delta_{\epsilon}(x)f(x)dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\frac{1}{2\epsilon} f(x)dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}2\epsilon\cdot \frac{1}{2\epsilon} f(\xi),
$$
where due to the mean value theorem $\xi\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$.

Hence we can conclude that
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}f(\xi)=f(0),
$$
which gives you a "*proof*" of the original formula.